# Qlikview: Hidden Sheet Information

Tags: qlikview

getsheetbyId can be used to access a hidden sheet but for that sheetid is required.
like:
    ActiveDocument.GetSheetByID("SH03");
How to get the hidden sheet id's corresponding to each hidden sheet in a qlikview Document.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, it is clear that you cannot access hidden sheets (i.e. sheets with a visibility condition set) via QlikView macro. As far as I can determine, this is due to the QlikView security model.

If a sheet is visible, you can access a sheet's ID as follows (e.g. for the active sheet):

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.GetProperties.SheetID
```

This will give you a string with the ID in the format `Document\<sheet id>` for example, `Document\SH01`.

If you wish to transform this into just the ID, you can use this:

```
fullShtID = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.GetProperties.SheetID
shtID = mid(fullShtID,instr(fullShtID,"\")+1)
```

`shtID` will then give you just `SH01` etc.

However, for "hidden" sheets, the easiest method would be to set the condition on the sheets visibility to a variable, and then alter the variable from your macro code. This would allow you to display the "hidden" sheet, record the ID (as above), and you could then hide it again by setting the variable. Apart from this workaround, there is no direct way to do it.

Comment: this method is for sheets that are not hidden. And while executing the last "for loop" gives an error ActiveDocument.Sheets is not defined. I want to get the hidden sheet id's in a qlikview Document.

Comment: Currently, I am using this : NO_Of_SHEETS = QvDoc.NoOfSheets
and then a for loop
For j=0 To NO_OF_SHEETS-1 
QvDoc.GetSheet(j).GetProperties.SheetId
Next :  but NoofSheets does not capture hidden sheets